# Twitter api returns truncated description

Tags: twitter, rss

I am using `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=[username]&include_rts=true&rpp=100`

To get the user's tweets, but for some reason most of the tweets' description is truncated, is there any way I can get the complete description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the RSS feeds don't contain the full tweets.

If you replace .rss with .xml or .json, then you will get the full text.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=[username]&include_rts=true&rpp=100
```

You will then have to transform the JSON or XML into RSS.